# Sum multiple columns in multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have following data structure for sales:

```
id  year  M01  M02  M03  M04  M05 M06 M07 M08 M09 M10 M11 M12
 1  2020    0    5    4    0   10   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 1  2019    4    3    0    0    6   0   7   0   8   0   0  10
 2  2020    0    5    4    0   10   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 2  2019    4    3    0    0    6   0   7   0   8   0   0  10
```

I need to know how many products with id=1 were sold for the last 12 month. If we are in June 2020 I need to sum M01, M02, M03, M04, M05 (WHERE year=2020) and M06, M07, M08, M09, M10, M11, M12 (WHERE year=2019) WHERE id=1. I should get a value of 36.

Please, any suggestions on how to do that in MySQL?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend against denormalized table like that. I'd suggest normalizing it with Month and Value fields. This is only the beginning of many to come complexities. The table above should only be a view.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to deal with this structure... Many thanks to Gordon Linoff! You saved me. The only correction: date >= curdate - interval 1 year. Well, I had to introduce several more modifications beause of old MySQL version, but, in principle, that's what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix your data model.  Unpivot and then aggregate:

```
with reasonable_format as (
      select id, year, str_to_date(concat(year, '-01-01'), '%Y-%m-%d') as date, m01 as amount from sales union all
      select id, year, str_to_date(concat(year, '-02-01'), '%Y-%m-%d') as date, m02 from sales union all
      . . .
      select id, year, str_to_date(concat(year, '-02-01'), '%Y-%m-%d') as date, m12 from sales 
    )
select sum(amount)
from reasonable_format rf
where id = 1 and date <= curdate - interval 1 year;
```

`reasonable_format` is what your data *should* look like.